# ArcGIS 10.1 Crashes when updating address locator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, address, serious-application-error

I keep getting a "ArcGIS has encountered a serious error and needs to close" crash dialogue box whenever I try to update an address locator imported from one server to another (updating the location of the reference database).

I've tried closing ArcMap and just using ArcCatalogue, still doesn't work.

I'm on a 3Ghz/4G RAM relatively new (<1 year) PC at work.

Can anyone help me with a work-around for this?

Answer (score 2):

Consider yourself lucky for having received an error message :-) I ran into a similar problem after changing the path names for some of my shapefiles. My computer is brand new and ArcMap does not necessarily get hung up in your hardware. Its own complexity could be more than enough.

Look up ArcMap in the Windows Reliability logging system on Windows (7/Vista), you might be able to find a log specific to your problem there.

**When ArcMap acts up like this one of your best options is to start a fresh project.** If your project is not too complex justs start anew. It is not the optimal solution, but trying to understand what makes your ArcMap freeze could take more time than you care to use on it.

Comment: +1 "Its own complexity could be more than enough".